# Card Counting Techniques

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

If I want to choose $7$ cards from a deck of $52$, how many ways can I choose them if all of the $7$ cards have values between $2$ and $7$ inclusive? And all the $7$ cards have different values where you assume Jacks are different from Queens?

This has been confusing me.

For the first part can I first select $7$ from $10$ since all the values go up to $10$ then select $7$ from it?

And the second part can I group same values together and select $1$ from each group?

Comment: "*...if all of the 7 cards have values between 2 and 7 includes[sic]*"  This sentence does not make sense when with the second one as well.  Are these separate problems or the same problem?  If the same problem, then what does it matter that a jack is different from a queen since neither jacks nor queens have values between 2 and 7 and aren't being chosen anyways?

Comment: For the first part, there are four cards from each suit, so there are $4(7 - 1) = 24$ cards with ranks from $2$ to $7$ inclusive.  You are selecting $7$ of those $24$ cards.  For the second part, there are $13$ ranks ($2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$, $8$, $9$, $10$, $J$, $Q$, $K$, $A$), each with four suits.  You must seven of those ranks, and one of the four cards from each of the selected ranks.

Comment: They are two are different questions.

Comment: @KudzaisheMurewa, there are $7-1=6$ ranks with values $2$ to $7$ inclusive $(2,3,4,5,6,7)$.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas thank you!!

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thank you. That really clears my confusion.